# VBA won't close workbook, and keeps saving

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA and tried to write a macro that will refresh, save and close my workbook when I open it. It won't close the workbook, but just keeps on saving all the time in a newer version.

```
Sub Main()

Dim sngStartTime, sngTotaltime As Date                                            
Dim LstUpdateRow As Integer                                                     
sngStartTime=Now                                                                

LstUpdateRow = Workbooks("Quick").Worksheets("settings").Range("c60000").End(xlUp).Row + 1               
sngTotaltime = Now - sngStartTime                                                 
Workbooks("Quick").Worksheets("Settings").Cells(LstUpdateRow, 3) = Now                                   
Workbooks("Quick").Worksheets("Settings").Cells(LstUpdateRow, 4) = sngStartTime                          
Workbooks("Quick").Worksheets("Settings").Cells(LstUpdateRow, 5) = sngTotaltime                          

End Sub

Sub RefreshData()

Application.Run "RefreshEntireWorkbook"

Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"

Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "Main"

End Sub
```

ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Main
RefreshData

Workbooks("Quick").Close Savechanges:=true

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you run your code from?

Comment: Im running my code from "Thisworkbook" sheet can then calling the subs from my module. I just want it to refresh, save and close whenever I open my excel file.

Comment: If you debug your code step by step, does it loop somwhere or does the sub finish?

Comment: When I loop my two subs in modules, it refreshes and everything works fine. I believe the mistake is in my workbook, maybe the code: Workbooks("Quick").Close Savechanges:=true does not work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting:

```
Workbooks("Quick.xlsm").Close Savechanges:=true
```

Or whatever your extension is for that particular workbook.  I replicated the workbook (to an extent) and opened it as if you would yourself.  The file opened, did what it was told to do, saved and closed.

Comment: Glad to hear!  For future record I typically assign my workbook names to variables when calling them multiple times throughout the code (especially when bouncing between ThisWorkbook and Modules).  That way it would be like:

`Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Activeworkbook
Workbooks(wb.Name).Close SaveChanges=True`

If this answered your question please mark it as the correct answer.  Thanks!